# Checking if a char is a newline

Tags: c++

I'm doing an exercise in C++ Primer and basically I am using a switch statement to count the number of vowels in a text that I input.

I input the text using a while loop.

```
while(cin >> ch)
```

and proceed with the cases, a, e, i, o, u, incrementing an integer variable for the respective cases. Now the next part of the question says also count the spaces, tabs and newlines.

I tried doing

```
case ' ':
```

and so forth using '\t' and '\n'. But it seems like it doesn't compute these cases. I also tried just using a default and using an if else statement

```
default:
    if(ch == ' ')
        ++space;
```

etc. But this doesn't proceed either. I also tried putting in the integer values of ' ', '\t', '\n'. What am I doing wrong here? Also, I know that if I use isspace() I can count the combined total but I need to compute each one individually. I'm not sure why the equality test won't do the job.

Answer (score 12):

By default, formatted input from streams skips leading whitespace. You need to either disable skipping of leading whitespaces or use one of the functions which won't skip spaces:

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws; // disables skipping of leading whitespace
char c;
while (std::cin.get(c)) {  // doesn't skip whitespace anyway
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to read in the white spaces? At this point in the book the technique you mentioned hasn't been covered. There has to be a simpler solution.

Comment: @Comrade: you could use `std::getline(std::cin, str)` where `str` is a `std::string`. It would read the spaces but newlines need to be counted separately by the number of successful calls to `std::getline()` (although it may yield a wrong result if the last line is terminated with a newline). You can also `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` to iterate over the sequence of `char`s (which is probably the fastest approach) but I doubt that this is covered in the book.

Comment: The part that counts the vowels requires me to count both lower case and upper case vowels using one case for the two. So in the switch statement I actually have switch(tolower(ch)). If I use getline(cin,str) where str is a string, is there an analogous function to tolower() that I can use for a string?

Comment: @Comrade: You'd need to look at the individual characters or use an algorithm to turn all characters into one of the cases, e.g., `std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return tolower(c); })`. BTW, note that `char` may be signed and `tolower()` (and family) require a positive argument, i.e., you need to convert your `char` to an `unsigned char` before using `tolower()`!

Comment: Count the number of `getline()`s! You can also specify the character used to determine when the line ends (it defaults to `'\n'`) and use a character which isn't used in the file (e.g. `'\0'` might work).

Answer (score 1):

As said by Dietmar, white spaces are skipped by default. You could use [cin.getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to provide your own string delimiter instead of white space characters. I would say this is a generally easier way of reading input compared to using `cin.get()`.